# Убрать значения, которые повторяются в словаре

Tags: c#, .net

У меня есть словарь:

```
IDictionary<string, List<Dict>>

public class Dict
{ 
   public string Name { 
     get; 
     set;
   }
   public byte[] Data { 
     get; 
     set;
   }
}
```

У меня вопрос, как я могу исключить все повторяющиеся значения для поля `Name` во всем словаре? Т.е. получается как бы делать фильтрацию словаря, при этом, все значения `Value` которые повторяются, мне необходимо удалять. Т.е. если в ключе "Key1" и "Key2" в списке есть поле `Name` с одинаковым значением, то необходимо исключить это значение для ключа.

Тестовые данные что-то вроде токого:

```
{"key1", {"NameОne", <data>}, {"NameTwo", <data>}}
{"key2", {"NameОne", <data>}, {"NameFour", <data>}}
```

Получиться должно это:

```
{"key1", {"NameОne", <data>}, {"NameTwo", <data>}}
{"key2", {"NameFour", <data>}}
```

Comment: Из какого из ключей вам надо исключить? Из обоих?

Comment: @tym32167  добавил, что должно получиться

Comment: @artem55555p Словарь сами заполняете или "внешний код"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот пишешь пишешь ответ, а потом тебя опережают. Остаавлю свой вариант для галочки :)

```
IDictionary<string, List<Dict>> data = new Dictionary<string, System.Collections.Generic.List<UserQuery.Dict>>();
data.Add("key1", new List<Dict> { new Dict() { Name = "NameОne" }, new Dict() {Name="NameTwo"}});
data.Add("key2", new List<Dict> { new Dict() { Name = "NameОne" }, new Dict() {Name="NameFour"}});

HashSet<string> names = new HashSet<string>();

foreach(var item in data)
{       
    item.Value.RemoveAll(i => !names.Add(i.Name));      
}
```

Comment: Хм, тут есть хитрость. А если в `key1` повторяется `NameOne` два раза? У меня не получилось с LINQ.

Comment: А, понял. Круто, чё.

Comment: tym32167 + вам от меня :-)

Comment: я пробую сейчас с помощью RemoveAll сделать, но пока никак))

Comment: @artem55555p если вы скопируете тот код, что я привел, и запустите, то получите именно тот результат, что хотите

Comment: @VladD да, немного замороченно получилось, но зато коротко :)

Answer (score 3):

Ну например как-то так:

```
HashSet<string> usedNames = new HashSet<string>();
foreach (List<Dict> ld in collection.Values)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ld.Count; /* nothing */)
    {
        if (!usedNames.Add(ld[i].Name))
            ld.RemoveAt(i);
        else
            i++;
    }
}
```

(Не нашёл изящного решения с LINQ.)

Comment: Всю жизнь это делали с декрементом)

Comment: @vp_arth: Декремент делает противоположный порядок удаления, это может быть важно.

Comment: ну да, действительно, в set добавится последний тогда)